# Parsing JSON string IOS - HTML characters

Tags: ios, json

In JSON response from web service ,  string contains HTML characters .
for example "text":"\x3ca href\x3d\x22http://word.... " etc etc

I am using SBJSON parser. Parsing( converting to dictionary ) is getting failed.

I think i need to replace those HTML characters with actual characters before giving to SBJSON parser. Is there any utility method for the same ?

Any help is really appreciated.

-mia

Answer (score 0):

Your first JSON char is wrong. '\x3ca' is not a valid JSON char. Your encoding goes wrong somewhere. The JSON equivalent for '<' is '\x3c'.
If you replace in your example '\x3ca' with '\x3c' you will get parsing result 
"< href="http://word ..."
My suggestion is check how the web service encodes special characters such as <, >, &, = and so on in the response it sends. I think that's where the error is.

(And as a parenthesis, those are JSON chars, not HTML chars :P)

Comment: First of all its not my Web Service :-). Its a response from Googles unofficial dictionary API.Your suggestion worked fine( thanks for that ) but parsing still failed . I tried like this  --   NSString *temp = @" { \"text\":\"\x3c href\x3d\x22http://word....\" }";
    NSDictionary *tempdict = [parser objectWithString:temp error:nil];
    NSLog(@"json string = %@",temp);
    NSLog(@"converted dict = %@",tempdict);
AND oupput is    json string =  { "text":"< href="http://word...." }
converted dict = (null) .....  Any Help on this ??

Comment: try using the error parameter as well, see what it saids. On your example try something like this: NSError *error = nil; NSString *temp = yourString; NSDictionary *tempDict = [parser objectWithString:temp error:&error]; and log the error.

Comment: This is the error "  error  = Error Domain=org.brautaset.SBJsonParser.ErrorDomain Code=0 "Illegal start of token [h]" UserInfo=0x6b2e960 {NSLocalizedDescription=Illegal start of token [h]}

Comment: yep, same issue as in the example you gave. Search your JSON string and try to identify other invalid JSON chars.

Answer (score 0):

SBJSON is expecting the keys to be enclosed in "" otherwise it will complain about whatever the first char of the first key is.